# I am coding a website, but bold and italics aren't working

Tags: google-chrome, web, italic

I am trying to make a website ([Sponge](http://www.spongemc.cf/)) and when I try to do bold and stuff but it just wont work!
look at it and see how annoying it is!

My code:
[Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/vuqoworofe.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header tags `<h#>` often apply `font-weight: bold` by default.  I'm not sure why all of your text is in headers, but it probably shouldn't be.

Put the bulk of your text in paragraph `<p>` tags and adjust your CSS to format the paragraphs how you'd like, using:

```
p { /*Style goes here*/ }
```

Or, you can apply a class to your paragraphs to adjust their styles individually or in groups.  If you're not sure how, Google a CSS tutorial.

This is just a quick edit of your code. It's not going to be perfect, but hopefully it leads you in the right direction.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sponge - Home</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
.hotbar {
    background-color: #808080;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
.about {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="hotbar" height="7%" width="100%">
<img align="left" src="http://www.spongemc.cf/home/images/logo.png" alt="logo" height="7%" width="7%">
<h1 align="center"><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.spongemc.cf/home/">Home</a></h1>
</div>
<div class="about">
<br /> <!-- Assuming all those empty header tags for for spaces - you could also use padding-top in the div or margin-top for the first h2 tag -->
<h2>What are we?<h2>
<p>We are a Minecraft server dedicated to people having fun!</p>
<p>You can have fun and play prison at <i>Sponge.minehut.gg</i>,</p>
<p>or you can play farming and Skyblock at <i>spongemc.net</i></p>
<p>Or you could just sit there doing nothing (I don't recomend this),</p>
<p>so what are you doing, <b>JOIN NOW!</b></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```